# Power amplifier simulation

Tags: power-amplifier

[image: PA]

I have simulated the circuit with the following values. VDD = 1.8V, Vin is a sine wave with fin = 450MHz, pin = -5dBm, L1 = 12.5nH, C1 = 10pF, RL=50 ohm. I also gave a biasing dc voltage at the gate of MOSFET as 1V.
I got the following graph after simulation.

[image]

The red graph is the input sine wave. The yellow graph is the current at the drain of MOSFET and the green one is the voltage at the drain of MOSFET. But I am not exactly getting what the graph means or how to interpret it? If I am using it as a power amplifier how can I improve the output values of voltage and currents?

Comment: What is the FET gm? and the FET C_drain_bulk? Can this FET have any chance of driving 50 ohms? Do you need a PI matching ? Is "L" matching the best choice?

Comment: Embed this to your original question. Voting to close. Also, I note that you haven't formally accepted one answer to your previous 17 questions. Is there are good reason for this? Most folk regard it is a fair fee to get continued good support on questions.